# Keyword: How can I access a keyword's metadata field value?

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, keyword, metadata

We have a category called ProductType with keywords to denote each type and we have a metadata schema called Product Group Metadata associated for each keyword. This metadata schema has three fields. 2 text fields and 1 drop down field.

I've tried using the following:

```
var keywordMeta = keyword.KeywordMeta;
if (keywordMeta != null)
{
    var metaNameDictionary = keywordMeta.NameValues;
    var metaNameEnumerator = metaNameDictionary.GetEnumerator();

    while (metaNameEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var currentMetaDe = (DictionaryEntry)metaNameEnumerator.Current;
        var currentMeta = (NameValuePair)currentMetaDe.Value;
        if (currentMeta != null)
        {
            // Process each metadata field.
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the keyword.KeywordMeta returns 0 despite having a metadata associated with the keyword and the loop is skipped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are publishing it to database?

Comment: Oops! I've republished the categories in Tridion and it all seems to work now. My bad!

Comment: Could you add that information as an answer? That way, someone else might be helped in the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the KeywordMeta property returns 0 is because the changes have not been republished in Tridion. Once you republish the categories, it should return the metadata you're looking for.